# Verb for "frequently editing a post to make it appear at the top of the forum"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word (Internet slang welcome) for "frequently editing a post to make it appear at the top of the forum"?

Comment: I'd call it SEO. (Stack Exchange Optimization) ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The verb *bump* refers to editing a post and making it appear on the main page but it does not refer to the frequency. You may write for example

> Users who frequently **bump** their posts might be doing it to gain more
>   reputation. However I do it to improve the quality of my posts.

Comment: Regarding your example usage, is it really considered `bumping` if you edit your post to improve its quality?

Comment: If your idea is not to really bump it for bump's sake, but a real edit, can we call it '*float*'?